# How to get Altitude using GPS in android without INTERNET?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, google-play-services

I am working one of the application which need latitude,longitude and altitude. And I have succeed for fetching Latitude and Longitude using Fused Location but I would like to get altitude or elevation from android device without Internet.

This application gets all 3 params i.e , Lat,Long and altitude without Internet. How it is possible?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilyabogdanovich.geotracker&hl=en

Comment: Got the solution by using NMEA in android.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128990/does-gps-require-internet), you don't need internet for GPS.

> **GPS** is basically a satellite based positioning system that is designed to calculate geographic coordinates based on timing information received from multiple satellites in the GPS constellation. GPS has a relatively slow time to first fix (TTFF), and from a cold start (meaning without a last known position), it can take up to 15 minutes to download the data it needs from the satellites to calculate a position. [**A-GPS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS) used by cellular networks shortens this time by using the cellular network to deliver the satellite data to the phone.

However, all that is derived that is Geographic Coordinates (latitude/longitude) is impossible to obtain more from GPS only. So you need an internet connection to get the Lat,Long and altitude.

You may also check this thread: [Use FusedLocationServiceApi without internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232911/use-fusedlocationserviceapi-without-internet-connection)